# Define order in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have defined some struct in elixir and now I would like to compare those struct in a way that I decide.

Basically I would like to write the >, >=, <, <= and == for the structs I define.

Is this possible?

Comment: All those operators exist by default for structs. Can you be a bit more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I ask because your question suggests you're thinking OO, not FP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can however sort in any way you wish by using `Enum.sort/2` or `Enum.sort_by/2`. For example:

```
iex> Enum.sort_by [%{name: "foo"}, %{name: "bar"}], fn data -> data.name end
[%{name: "bar"}, %{name: "foo"}]
```

You can also just define a compare function in your module that does the proper comparison, similar to how the Version module in Elixir works:

```
iex> Version.compare "1.0.0", "2.0.0"
:lt
```